# Access column value from within knex query

Tags: node.js, sqlite, knex.js

I'd like to update the value of column A by applying a function to column B.

Is there a simple solution of the form:

```
knex('table')
    .update({
      colA: func(${colB})
    })
```

Comment: Is this the SQL statement that you are hoping to produce? : `UPDATE table set colA = func(colB)`

Comment: Yeah.  In the meantime I wrote a script outside of knex that did what I wanted but it would still be nice to know if it's possible with knex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this within Knex.

For SQL functions which don’t have explicit support in Knex you use `knex.raw(SQLstring, parmArray)` to encapsulate a SQL snippet or `knex.schema.raw(...)` to produce an entire SQL statement. And you use single question marks `?` for value replacements, and double question marks `??` for field identifier replacements. ([see link](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-identifier-syntax))

So the SQL:  `UPDATE table SET colA = func(colB)`

... can be produced by including a SQL snippet: *(you were close)*

```
knex('table')
    .update({
       colA: knex.raw( 'func(??)', ['colB'] ) 
     })
```

... or as full raw SQL:

```
knex.schema.raw( 'UPDATE table SET ?? = func(??)', ['colA', 'colB'] )
```

Cheers, Gary.